# What do numbers inside parenthesis mean / Terminal?

Tags: typescript, terminal

While working in Terminal, when I get errors the message shown like following:

```
TypeScript error: /Users/AdminUser/Desktop/Ionic 2 MyApp/NewApp/app/pages/map/map.ts(35,25): Error TS1005: ';' expected.

TypeScript error: /Users/AdminUser/Desktop/Ionic 2 MyApp/NewApp/app/pages/map/map.ts(38,22): Error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I can't find anywhere what do the numbers **(35, 25)** and **(38, 22)** inside parenthesis mean?

Answer (score 2):

They tell you where the error happened. The first number is the number of the line in the file, the second number is the number of the character in that line where the error begins.

Comment: But it seems to be of a weird behavior, because according to that logic an error must be on "maps.Map" dot, where Terminal console wants me to put ";" instead "."


this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

Comment: @AlexandrBelov Counting indentation? Keep in mind tabs count as one space.

Comment: No, but if count indentations it falls on "goog (here it wants me to put ";") le"

Comment: Try making an error elsewhere and compare what you feel should be the position vs. what the compiler is telling you, that'll give you an offset that you can use the find the real position. Alternatively, if you use a properly configured text editor like sublime with the typescript plugin it'll highlight the error in particular.

Comment: @AlexandrBelov Regardless, that is what the line numbers mean. We'd be happy to help looking at more of your code for this error in particular but that should be a separate question.

Comment: Paarth, thank you for your concern! I will try to figure out what have been done wrong.